# Gradle copy file into generated jar (after :jar Task)

Tags: file, gradle, jar, copy, rename

It it possible to copy certain files into / within the generated .jar AFTER it has been finished? E.g. I would like to simply rename one file after the compilation is done.

Ofc, one could also extract the jar, change the file and repack it again as a jar. Though I wonder whether this is optimal or not.

Comment: Which file do you want to rename? .java/.kt file?

Comment: For me it's important to rename after the compilation - that would mean I would like to rename a class file. Just like I would do manually by opening the jar with WinRar, renaming the class and closing WinRar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) lib. It is plugin for Gradle.

[Guide](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/relocation/) for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll look into that asap!